# How to get the node's innertext when the node tag has variable name

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an xml file where the tag names are like this

```
<PhysicalDrive0>
</PhysicalDrive0>
....
<PhysicalDrive8>
</PhysicalDrive8>
```

Here the number of physical drives is unknown or can vary. Hence I can't manually look for nodes like

```
xmlDoc.SelectNodes("../PhysicalDrive0");
```

So I suppose it would be better to incorporate some sort of regular expression like thing. So far whatever I searched mostly was working with attributes.

I tried

```
XmlNodeList list = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("..//*[starts-with(name(),'PhysicalDrive')]");
            Console.WriteLine("list count "+list.Count);
```

Which gave me a count of 0.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better use `local-name()` than `name()`. You may have namespaces (prefix) issues with the `name()` function. And if you start at document root, use `//` and not `..//`. You end up with the following xpath:

```
//*[starts-with(local-name(),'PhysicalDrive')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `System.Xml.Linq`:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
var list = xDoc.Descendants()
    .Where(e =>
        e.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("PhysicalDrive"))
    .Select(e => e.Value)
    .ToList();
```